# Enviar correo y adjuntar archivo con un servicio web

Tags: c#, .net, webservice, windows-mobile, embebido

Lo que quiero hace es poder enviar un correo con unos datos que se digiten desde mi proyecto de Windows CE, el problema que presento es que creo el sitio web y coloco mis dos códigos tanto el del correo como el de exportar los datos a excel pero entonces me surgen dos problemas.

1. Con el tema de excel, ¿cómo hago yo para decirle a mi programa que escoja los 14 Labels y los 7 TextBox que se encuentran en mi proyecto de Windows CE?, Porque si yo hago el llamado éste me dice que no existen esos Labels y los TextBox.
2. ¿Cómo hacer para que el código del correo el cual también se encuentra en el servicio web me envée la información de ese Excel ya que este me envia el archivo pero me lo envía con unas palabras que puse de ejemplo?, si yo llamo al método el cual contiene la exportación de excel dentro de eso me arroja un error.
3. ¿Cómo hago para llamar ese servicio desde mi proyecto de Windows CE?

Adjunto los codigos que estoy manejando

**CÓDIGO DE EXCEL**

```
public void exporta_a_excel()
{

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass excel = new ApplicationClass();

    excel.Application.Workbooks.Add(true);

    int ColumnIndex = 0;

    foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
    {

        ColumnIndex++;

        excel.Cells[1, ColumnIndex] = col.Name;

    }

    int rowIndex = 0;

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {

        rowIndex++;

        ColumnIndex = 0;

        foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
        {

            ColumnIndex++;

            excel.Cells[rowIndex + 1, ColumnIndex] = row.Cells[col.Name].Value;

        }


    }

    excel.Visible = true;

    Worksheet worksheet = (Worksheet)excel.ActiveSheet;

    worksheet.Activate();

}
```

**CÓDIGO DEL CORREO**

```
public void Correo()
{

    MailMessage objeto_mail = new MailMessage();
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
    client.Port = 587;
    client.Host = "smtp-mail.outlook.com";
    client.Timeout = 10000;
    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxxxx@hotmail.com", "xxxx");
    objeto_mail.From = new MailAddress("xxxxx@hotmail.com");
    objeto_mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("xxxx@xxxxxx.com.co"));
    objeto_mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("xxxxx@outlook.com"));
    objeto_mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("xxxx@hotmail.com"));
    objeto_mail.Subject = "Pedidos";
    //List<string> Archivo = new List<string>();
    //Archivo.Add("");
    //Archivo.Add("");
    objeto_mail.IsBodyHtml = false;
    objeto_mail.Body = "se hizo el pedido y la orden esta adjuntada en el correo con un excell";
    client.EnableSsl = true;
    //client.Send(objeto_mail);

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))    // using UTF-8 encoding by default
    // using (var mailClient = new SmtpClient("localhost", 25))
    // using (var message = new MailMessage("me@example.com", "you@example.com", "Just testing", "See attachment..."))
    {

        writer.WriteLine("Comma,Seperated,Values,..."); //ESTO ME SALED EN EL ARCHIVO EXCEL
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;     // read from the start of what was written

        objeto_mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(stream, "Pedido.csv", "text/csv"));

        client.Send(objeto_mail);
    }



}
```

Todo esto esta en un servicio web, y hacer el llamado desde el formulario de Windows Ce en el cual está la base de datos, los Labels y los TextBox y el cual hasta el momento hace la operación de actualizar los datos, los cuales se deben ir insertando en el Excel el cual se envía por correo electrónico.

Las liberías que estoy utilizando para el correo son:

```
using OpenNETCF.Net.Mail;
using OpenNETCF.Net;
```

Y los datos que deben ir en el Excel son estos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: amigo, agrega las librerías que estás utilizando para enviar el correo, también un ejemplo del excel que estás generado, ayudaría mucho :)

Comment: Listo @fredyfx ahi estan las librerias y los datos que quiero que se coloquen en el excel

Comment: No entiendo muy bien cual es tu problema sin embargo te podría sugerir algunas cosas. En lugar de usar directamente `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` uses [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/ "EPPlus") ya que esta preparado para realizar libros de excel de manera bastante avanzada en un servidor web. Puedes leer hay mucha documentación en la web. [Aqui](http://zeeshanumardotnet.blogspot.mx/2011/06/creating-reports-in-excel-2007-using.html "Aqui") hay un ejemplo. En cuanto a como pasar los datos (o parametros, no comprendo muy bien) de un cliente al servidor lo podrías hacer enviando los datos e

Answer (score -1):

@Cristian R.M ,
te recomendaria mas fácil , es que envíes desde c# unos parametros de un sp de la bd
y ese sp con esos datos ya mande el correo adjunto