# SmtpExecption en windows Ce cuando se envia correos

Tags: c#, .net, embebido, windows-mobile

Cuando ejecuto mi comando de enviar correos electronicos me arroaja el error **SmtpExecption**, como podria solucionar este problema, el metodo que lo estoy enviando es con **OpenNETCF**

```
using OpenNETCF.Net.Mail;
using OpenNETCF.Net;
```

El error que arroja es el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: amigo, agrega el error a la pregunta :)

Comment: la verdad es que no recomendaria enviar mail desde un dispositivo, los mail los envias desde un servicio web implementado en el servidor

Comment: como un post a mailgun o sendgrid :D

Comment: pues lo estoy tratando de hacer como servicio
http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/21421/enviar-correo-y-adjuntar-archivo-con-un-servicio-web
pero entonces presento algunos problemas
@fredyfx ese es el error que me arroja

Comment: @CristianR.M, actualiza tu pregunta con el contenido de la excepción. Los comentarios fueron diseñados para pedir clarificaciones, dejar criticismo constructivo, o agregar información adicional.

Comment: Listo  ya agregue los errores que me arroja el dispositivo